# python will import lhapdf in wsl ubuntu, but can't find the pdf.info despite the paths being set correctly

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I am newish to wsl ubuntu, and recently have started working with lhapdf.  I have the lhapdf paths I believe correct as python will import lhapdf, but when I try to call a specific pdf file, I get the error:

```
>>> import lhapdf
>>> p = lhapdf.mkPDF('cteq6l1',0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "lhapdf.pyx", line 881, in python.lhapdf.mkPDF
File "lhapdf.pyx", line 829, in python.lhapdf.mkPDF_setmem
RuntimeError: Info file not found for PDF set 'cteq6l1'
```

I can physically see the cteq6l1.info and DAT file in the share folder (where the $LHAPDF_DATA_PATH is set).

I do not understand why python can not see the info files, and am would be happy for any advice on this matter.

I have tried some different path variations, to no avail.